# eclipse esp8266 COM Port ISSUE

Tags: python, makefile, arduino-esp8266

I am working on ESP8266 from Eclipse on Windows7.

I have never worked on Eclipse.I have started by taking reference from the internet which was by Jan Penninkhof lesson. But the problem is coming from my side is during flash a program in ESP8266, I got an error which is showed in last.I am unable to resolve the issue. I have checked the port in device manager and correct it in a makefile of particular project but still I'm getting this error.

During flash the error shows in console of eclipse:-

```
File "esptool.py", line 1270, in <module> File "esptool.py", line 
1179, in main File "esptool.py", line 71, in init File "serial_init_.pyo",
line 88, in serial_for_url File "serial\serialwin32.pyo", 
line 63, in open serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': 
WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.') mingw32-make.exe: *** [flash] 
Error 255 ../common_nonos.mk:310: recipe for target 'flash' faile
```

Comment: During flash the erroe shows in console of eclipse:- File "esptool.py", line 1270, in <module>
  File "esptool.py", line 1179, in main
  File "esptool.py", line 71, in __init__
  File "serial\__init__.pyo", line 88, in serial_for_url
  File "serial\serialwin32.pyo", line 63, in open
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
mingw32-make.exe: *** [flash] Error 255
../common_nonos.mk:310: recipe for target 'flash' failed

Comment: Please do not post the error in the comment next time. I put it in the question.